# Copy Data from DynamoDB to Redshift or RDS that has JSON column

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

I have a DynamoDB with 5 columns. One of them is a JSON column. I would like to copy this data to either Redshift or RDS. Redshift has no JSON column support out of the box, that's why the copy command fails.

```
[2017-10-12 10:54:21] error:  Unsupported Data Type: Current Version only supports Strings and Numbers
[2017-10-12 10:54:21] code:      9005
[2017-10-12 10:54:21] context:   Table Name = my_tabe_name
[2017-10-12 10:54:21] query:     3470
[2017-10-12 10:54:21] location:  table_dynamodb_scanner.cpp:235
[2017-10-12 10:54:21] process:   query0_23 [pid=28462]
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use either AWS data pipeline or if you have less amount of data run a python script generate csv or | separator data file and copy the file it to redshift. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-copydata-redshift.html

Comment: It's around 80 GB of Dynamo DB data. I guess that would take a little while

Comment: use varchar in redshift as the target then use redshift json functions against that.